# naukri.com login fails every time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, login-script

I am trying to create a script to update my naukri profile but I am facing issue with the login part as `naukri.com` has 2 pages for the same login window and out of those the pages, a random page is displayed. How to handle that? I've tried all the possible combinations of Xpath, but still nothing worked and any other locator technique is of no use as it is not common for both the pages.

Details:

https://www.naukri.com/nlogin/login

## Email ID / Username

```
<input type="text" id="usernameField" placeholder="Enter your Email ID or Username" rel="required:usernameField_required|blur" autocapitalize="none" value="">
```

Password

```
<input type="password" id="passwordField" placeholder="Enter your Password" rel="required:passwordField_required|blur" autocapitalize="none" value="">
```

https://login.naukri.com/nLogin/Login.php
Email ID:

```
<input type="text" name="USERNAME" id="emailTxt" placeholder="Enter Email ID" rel="regEmail" ref="emailRad" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" class="       err">
```

Password:

```
<input type="password" name="PASSWORD" id="pwd1" placeholder="Enter password" rel="logPass" maxlength="40" class="     err">
```

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_

Answer (score 0):

After driver.get(URL), use the following code

```
String URL1="https://www.naukri.com/nlogin/login";
String URL2="https://login.naukri.com/nLogin/Login.php";
String URL=driver.getCurrentUrl();
if(URL.equals(URL1)){
    driver.findElement(By.id("usernameField")).sendKeys("Username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordField")).sendKeys("password");
    } else if(URL.equals(URL2)) {
    driver.findElement(By.name("USERNAME")).sendKeys("Username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("PASSWORD")).sendKeys("password");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To login in into your **Naukri.com** account you can start from the initial `url` **https://www.naukri.com/** and proceed as per the following code block :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Naukri_Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='login_Layer']//div[@class='mTxt']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='eLoginNew']")).sendKeys("Abhresh@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pLogin']")).sendKeys("Abhresh");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='blueBtn']")).click();
    }
}
```